# Let $V = H_{0}^{1}(-1,1) \times H_{0}^{1}$ and $V^{\prime} = H^{-1}(-1,1) \times H^{-1}(-1,1)$ , $T : V \to V^{\prime}$ is compact?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $V = H_{0}^{1}(-1,1) \times H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$ and $V^{\prime} = H^{-1}(-1,1) \times H^{-1}(-1,1)$ the dual space of $V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{\ast}$. Consider $T : V \to V^{\prime}$ continuous.

$T((u,v),(\varphi , \phi)) = a((u,v),(\varphi , \phi))$, where

$$
a((u,v),(\varphi , \phi)) = -\lambda^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}(u\overline{\varphi} + v \overline{\phi})dx + i\lambda \int_{-1}^{1}(v\overline{\varphi} - u\overline{\phi})dx 
$$
$\forall(\varphi ,\phi) \in H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)\times H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$

I would like to show $T$ is compact. But how?

One way I thought of was to use compactness embedding from $H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$ to $L^{2}(-1,1)$ and continuous embedding from $L^{2}(-1,1)$ into $H^{-1}(-1,1)$.

But, I can't.